# Ubuntu freezes on first start after installation

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, freeze

I am currently using PopOS 22.04 on my PC, but I want to switch to ubuntu 22.04 (I'm already using Ubuntu on my Notebook and it has been great).
When I try to install Ubuntu the PC freezes while showing the Ubuntu logo on full screen.
I then used the save graphics mode and the installation succeeded, but on first startup after installation the PC freezes while showing the log in page.

PC Specs: Ryzen 3700x, RTX 2070, 120gb ssd, 16gb ram

Comment: did you install the correct graphics drivers?

Comment: If you fixed the issue as provided with your latest edit, please move that down to the ANSWER section on this Q&A site. You can then *accept* your answer as answered & gain the rep. from answering the question.  *Also if you believe this issue should not have occurred, that part of the edit belongs is a bug report & not here, so it can be actioned/fixed - see* https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue

1. Boot into recovery mode (holding shift on start up)
2. Enable networking
3. Open root terminal
4. Press enter
5. Install nvidia driver `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-dkms-515`